# How to run junit 3 with non default constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, junit3

I have a code base where they define junit test cases as  :

```
public class MyTest extends BaseTestCase
{
    public MyTest( String name )
    {
        super( name );
    }

    public void testSome() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue (1 == 1);
    }
}
```

How to do I run this test from eclipse? How do I supply the name in the constructor?

Comment: new MyTest("testSome")).run(); from some eclipse main file  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the implementation the why not pass the super types construction parameter  yourself i.e.

```
public class MyTest extends BaseTestCase
{
    public MyTest()
    {
        super( "My Test" );
    }

    public void testSome() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue (1 == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to remove the parameter to the MyTest constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run it directly as JUnit runner expect `'Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor'`  so you have to invoke it manually or as @shim cat have shown or do this per class

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" local setUp ");
}
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" local tearDown ");
}
```

but if you want to share it you can do this per 'TestSuite'

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" Global setUp ");
}
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" Global tearDown ");
}
```